How to neatly check the number of neighbors in 2D list, wrapping around to check opposite side when checking the edge
I'm writing a type of cellular automata That has a higher chance of making a cell be alive(1) the more neighbors it has but obviously get errors when trying to check the amount of neighbors on a cell on the edge or corner of the board since I can't check for example if the cell to the right of a cell on the far right is alive or not but I want it to then wrap around to the far left and check those ones.
I understand that I can check where the cell I'm looking at is but that would increase the amount of code in amt() to around 9 times the code which I think is too much and I assume there's probably a way to make it neater.
from random import randint

global board
board = []

csize = 69
rsize = 69

for col in range(csize):
    board.append([])
    for row in range(rsize):
        #board[col].append(0)
        if col == 0:
            board[col].append(1)
        else:
            board[col].append(0)

def ranize():
    for col in range(len(board)):
        for row in range(len(board)):
            board[col][row] = randint(0,1)


def check():
    for col in range(len(board)):
        for row in range(len(board)):
            if board[col][row] == 1:
                return True
    return False


def show():
    loc = "\n"
    for col in range(len(board)):
        for row in range(len(board[col])):
            if board[col][row] == 1:
                loc += "@ "
            else:
                loc += f"{amt(col, row)} "
        loc += "\n"
    print(loc, end = "\r")


def amt(col ,row):
    loc = 0

    if col != 0 and col != csize-1 and row != 0 and row != rsize-1:     #Center board
        if board[col-1][row-1] == 1:    #Check Col-1
            loc += 1
        if board[col-1][row] == 1:
            loc += 1
        if board[col-1][row+1] == 1:
            loc += 1
        if board[col][row-1] == 1:      #Check Col
            loc += 1
        if board[col][row+1] == 1:
            loc += 1
        if board[col+1][row-1] == 1:    #check Col+1
            loc += 1
        if board[col+1][row] == 1:
            loc += 1
        if board[col+1][row+1] == 1:
            loc += 1

    return(loc)


def onestep():
    if not check():
        input("All cells dead, press Enter to randomize board: ")
        ranize()

    for col in range(len(board)):
        for row in range(len(board[col])):
            neighbors = amt(col, row)
            ranum = randint(0, 8)
            if board[col][row] == 1:
                if 8-neighbors > ranum:
                    board[col][row] = 0
            else:
                if neighbors > ranum:
                    board[col][row] = 1


while True:
    show()
    onestep()
#    input()


Instead of adding 1, subtract 68 (or in general  size - 1).
